# How to get django template from django_pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, django, pandas

**How do you get django templates from a django_pandas dataframe?**

Documentation with django and pandas focuses on models. It does not trace the coding process from model to view to template.

Using the example here: https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas#dataframemanager it is possible to translate a django model to a pandas dataframe.

```
# models.py 

from django.db import models
from django_pandas.managers import DataFrameManager

class MyModel(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    wage = models.FloatField()

    objects = DataFrameManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Subsequently, you can manipulate the dataframe, for example, reseting the index.

Q1: **How should you use views.py to get that dataframe to a template?**

you might transform it using df.to_html() as per below, or use df.to_json(), but **I'm expecting because its Django that there is a best practice to place the df into a template.**

```
# views.py - here spits out html string, do I just resort to ElementTree?

from django.shortcuts import render
from django_pandas.io import read_frame
from .models import MyModel

def LookatMyModel(request):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    template_name = 'pandatest/page1.html'

    df = queryset.to_dataframe()
    #df = df.set_index('full_name') # effectively we can change the model.
    print (df.head())

    df1 = df.to_html()
    context = { 'object_list': df1}
    print(df1)
    return render (request, template_name, context,)


# templates/page1.html

{% block content %}
<h1>Pandas dataframe from MyModel</h1>
<ul>
{% for obj in object_list%} 
    <li>{{ obj }} ,{{ obj.full_name }} ,{{ obj.age }} </li>
{% endfor%}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Q2: **Can django_pandas contradict good django practice?** If in pandas, we reset an index, effectively, the django model relationships are being changed in a view. Is that bad practice?